# Failed to reset devices.list on /lxc/mailserver/system.slice/dovecot.service:

Tags: lxc

I am running dovecot in an 15.10 lxc container. When I restart the service I get the following error in the syslog.

```
Dec  4 03:02:04 mailserver systemd[1]: Failed to reset devices.list on /lxc/mailserver/system.slice/dovecot.service: Permission denied
```

It does not seem to affect the operation of the system, but I have not been looking very hard.

How do I go about solving this one?